# jQuery dialog box with dynamic table delete record button not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, dialog

I have been writing a script that opens a dialog box and within the dialog box there is a dynamic table with data pulled out of one of my databases. I have put delete buttons next to all the records so that staff can remove unnecessary records.
I was trying to use an click function that triggers an Ajax request which then deletes the record from the database instantly.
But what happens is that when I click the delete button it closes the dialog box and doesn't delete anything at all. I have copied my code bellow if that is of any help.

all help is greatly appreciated :)

```
 //including all jquery library

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
                    buttons: {

                "Add to Log": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "check_add.php",
                    data: $('#checkup').serialize(),

                    success: function(data) {

                             if(data == 0){//Failure 
                                    alert('Data was NOT saved in db!');
                                         }
                                 }
                });
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );


                },
                Exit: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }

        });

            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });


        $( "#reminder" ).dialog({
            width: 471,
            autoOpen: false,
                    buttons: {

                Exit: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

            $( "#remind" ).click(function() {
            $( "#reminder" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });


        $(".Delete").click(function() // here the delete function
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var rowid = $this.attr('name');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'check_del.php',
            data: {
            'id': rowid
                },
            success: function(data) {

        if(data == 1){//Success 
             alert('Sucess');
          }
        if(data == 0){//Failure 
             alert('Data was NOT saved in db!');
          }
            }
 });
        }); 


    });
    </script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<button id="opener">Add Damage</button>
<button id="remind">Reminder</button>

<div id="dialog" style="font-size:small;">
<form name="checkup" method="post" id="checkup"> 
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <strong>Cases:</strong></td><td><input name="cases" type=text  placeholder="Cases ID" maxlength="7" style="width:129px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><strong>Comments:</strong></td>
    <td> <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comments Box"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<?php
```

//database connection stuff

```
$sql="select * from $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>


<div id="reminder" style="font-size:small;">
<form name="remind" method="post" id="remind"> 
    <table bordercolor="#000000" border="1" style="border:thin;">
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Cases</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>   </th>

<?
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cases=strtoupper($rows['cases']);
?>

    <tr>
    <td><? echo $rows['hg']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $cases;?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['surname']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['model']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $rows['comments']; ?></td>
    <td><button  name="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"  class="Delete">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

    </table> 
<?
}
?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried watching the ajax traffic in chrome (right click anywhere on page, inspect element, click the 'Network' tab) or in firefox (using firebug...also selecting network tab)?

Comment: yes i have watched the traffic using firebug in firefox something does show up for a second but it goes away before i can get a screen shot or even read it.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing i  changed my code slightly. I have pasted the working section of html for the button and the jquery code

HTML BUTTON

```
<input name="<? echo $rows['id'];?>" type="button"   value="Delete"  />
```

Jquery function

```
$("input[type='button']").on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var userid = $this.attr('name');

            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'check_del.php',
            data: {
            'id': userid

                },
            success: function(data) {

        if(data == 1){//Success 
             alert('Sucess');
          }
        if(data == 0){//Failure 
             alert('Data was NOT saved in db!');
          }
            }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".Delete").live('click',function() {
 // your code go here
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated - try to use `on` with jQuery 1.7 or greater, and choose `delegate` over `live` with older versions.

Comment: im sorry Kelly i dont quite understand what u mean?

Comment: i have tryed to use. "on" instead of "live' but it hasnt worked im still facing the same problem